# Mongoose change fieldname before Insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema like this

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
 first_name: "john",
 last_name: "doe"
})
```

On my api route i will receive the data in response body like

```
request.body = {
  firstName: "john",
  lastName: "doe"
}
```

I want to implement an insert to the mongodb after changing the payload fields from camelcase to underscore

I cannot update the casing of either the Schema or Api Spec.
Is there any solution which i cam implement which is not much expensive interms of db performance ?

i had a general look up and find out about `pre('save')` but that require much more coding and needed manipulation of entire objects through code.

also updating after inserting is not much of a solution.

i am currently using mongoose save for insert.
i could switch to `insertMany` of `updateMany` (with upsert: true) or any other insert methods

Answer (score 0):

You can simply map the request payload to the desired mongo-document structure:

```
app.post('/add-user', async (req, res) => {
  await User.create({ first_name: req.firstName, last_name: req.lastName });
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Is in't this like manually recreating the object again ?.
i do have both insert and update operations in that case i may have to write it twice...

Comment: i was expecting some more of a generic approach
for eg in get i was using aggregate in which i have a common object mapping for user schema
{
    firstName: "$first_name"
}
is there any possibility i can reuse a common object for all mapping CURD operations ?

Comment: You have to write it exactly once if you extract this into a mapper-function and use this function both for update and insert handlers. I don't know if there's a way to do this through mongoose.